# Mamba/Micromamba: Add path to environment

Tags: python, conda, mamba

Conda has the `conda develop` command, which can be used to add paths to local python projects (e.g. self-written libraries that aren't distributed as packages) to the module path of an environment.

How can I achieve a similar effect with mamba / micromamba (or even independently of the package manager)? The lack of solutions I was able to find on this question makes me wonder if maybe the `conda develop` solution is an anti-pattern.

I would also prefer a solution that doesn't require me to package my dependency library (so that it e.g. can be installed via `pip install -e`)

Comment: It seems like you should [not be using `conda develop`](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4251) as it is pretty much unmaintained and (officially?) deprecated. Why don't you just use `pip install` perhaps with `-e`?

Comment: I haven't considered `pip install -e`, but the very github discussions you linked mention problems on mixing `pip install` and `conda install` (or in my case `mamba install`). I'll try this though.

Comment: `pip install -e` can be safe if you follow some rules of thumb: 1) have all dependencies already installed 2) the installed package is not-compiled. If compilation is involved, it should be packaged. Also, `conda develop` still requires you to package - that is, it installs *Conda* packages in a symlinked mode (similar to what `pip install -e` does for Python packages). Conda develop is not actively maintained because it hasn't really needed any adaptation. Most of recent work on Conda is about solving, not about install procedures.